# Accessing $get asynchronously with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am trying to use $get to load a file with jquery and I want to be able to call back the function and wait for the result outside of the query.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
  filename = "./moonlight_sonata_diameter.data";
  items = readData(filename, callback);

  function readData(filename, callback) {

    $.get(filename, function(data) {
      items = data.split(/\r?\n/).map(pair => pair.split(/\s+/).map(Number));
       callback(items);

    });
  }
```

[See the full code on Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/9XVbEU?p=preview)

Comment: Do you have a function called callback in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never defined your callback function.

```js
  var filename = "./moonlight_sonata_diameter.data";

  var fn_callback = function(items) {
    // do what you need to do with your items here ...
  }
  
  // pass the callback function "fn_callback" as a parameter to readData()
  readData(filename, fn_callback); 

  function readData(filename, callback) {
    $.get(filename, function(data) {
      var items = data.split(/\r?\n/).map(pair => pair.split(/\s+/).map(Number));
      callback(items);
    });
  }
```

On a side note: you should not use the same name for global variables and function parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work yet: http://plnkr.co/edit/9XVbEU?p=preview

Comment: The problem is with your other code. You never reach the code you've changed because `plot1.setCrosshair()` and `plot1.move()` are not defined. I have removed those lines and the callback code works. Please use your browser's console to identify and solve such problems.